# strict_types doesn't work when included

Tags: php

I have a method that returns true or false, however when I add a type declaration `isAdmin() : string` it is not throwing a fatal error.

I have `declare(strict_types=1);` in a second file that is included before the class. 
Example:

**file1.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
include "file1.php";

class Test
{    
    public function user() : int
    {
        return true;   
    }
}

$test = new Test();
var_dump($test->user());
```

This code won't throw a fatal error. Instead the var_dump returns the bool as `int(1)`. If I change method type to a string, var_dump returns the bool as `string(1) "1"`.

How can I avoid putting `declare(strict_types=1);` in every model file?

Comment: That mean you function return a string and you return a boolean.

Comment: @headmax think he's asking why this passes if he has `strict_types` enabled. This example __should__ fail but apparently its passing.

Comment: Additionally, you can skip the if statement, just `return isset($this->type) && $this->type == 3`

Comment: This question shouldn't be down voted then

Comment: I found the reason this is happening. I edited my post.

Comment: ok didn't read all the post ;) to avoid i guess you have to inject to the bootstrap constructor and then you can enable or disable inside the controllers.

Comment: @headmax Can you elaborate?

Comment: @pidari Ok imagine you have a file and there you put <?php declare(strict_types=1);  and you want it to a page or into a method you can include this file where you want globally or use PHP7 syntax trait if you want to add somewhere exactly if you declared inside a specific class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not currently possible to globally declare strict typing in PHP. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict):

> It is possible to enable strict mode on a per-file basis

And

> Strict typing applies to function calls made from within the file with strict typing enabled, not to the functions declared within that file. If a file without strict typing enabled makes a call to a function that was defined in a file with strict typing, the caller's preference (weak typing) will be respected, and the value will be coerced.

My guess is that, in part, this was to maintain compatibility amongst packages. What if you enable if globally and some package you're using requires strict typing to be off?

Until further notice you'll have to declare it in every file you're going to be using it.

Comment: Upvoted, because the technical part is correct. But FYI, this was never about compatibility and it's not just "for now" - that is an opinion that you are adding.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I don't remember where I read that, but it's not in the manual. I'll edit it.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I won't use it for now.